# Java Catching Runtime Warnings/Detecting Graphics Card

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, javafx-8, warnings

The application I'm developing needs to run JavaFX8 (3D support) if able and default to JavaFX (2D) if the system my application is being run on can't support 3D.

The system I'm running on has no graphics card and cannot support 3D on runtime. The 3D support is a future proofing measure. When Netbeans compiles my code there are no warnings or errors. However, there are runtime warnings (not errors or exceptions). I've tried throwing a try/catch around the declarations that create the warnings but nothing is caught.

I need a way to either detect these warnings or detect whether or not the system can support 3D.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please provide an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with whatever you've tried until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested (as I don't have system that would properly test this), but try

```
Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D);
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple